# Keeping strings with wild cards intact while adding CRLF to begining of string

Tags: string, notepad++

I want replace every occurrence of a month string in a horse racing program. In example, Jan1 to Jan31, Feb1 to Feb28 and so on and put a CRLF in front of it to create a new line. I need to keep the date intact when the new line is created. That's the part I can't figure out using a wild card and keeping the original date intact.

Swal

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I should have said, I wanted to do it in NotePad++. I'm sorry about that. I am writing a horse race program in Delphi 5 but I wanted to load the lines in from a PDF text file with the dates already seperated from the long stream of characters. I thought I do do this quickly in NodePad++ before loading the characters in my program.  Swal

Comment: @Swal20 Can you provide an example of the data you are trying to process?

Comment: 10 Sts - $5,763Mar17 11 Lon -2 ft-1 F-nw7000lcd 6600Feb2 9 Lon -10gd-4 F-nw7000lcd

Comment: 10 Sts - $5,763Mar17 11 Lon -2 ft-1 F-nw7000lcd 6600Feb2 9 Lon -10gd-4 F-nw7000lcd  It looks like the text to the left except there's 900K of it. I took out some data in the middle of the line to make it easy. I want to start a new line with Mar17 and Feb2 I can do this Mar\d+ to \r\nMar but that doesn't carry over the 17 part of the date. I can't figure that one out. I guess I would have to do 1 month at a time even if I solve the first problem, getting the numbers over. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Jon I'm going to repost this with the tag NotePad++ and an updated question now that I understand how this all works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In NotePad++ I'm trying to replace Jan\d+ with \r\nJan but it's not working the way I thought](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284546/in-notepad-im-trying-to-replace-jan-d-with-r-njan-but-its-not-working-the)