# In NotePad++ I'm trying to replace Jan\d+ with \r\nJan but it's not working the way I thought

Tags: regex, notepad++

```
10 Sts - $5,763Jan17 11 Lon -2 ft-1 Janet HallFeb2 9 Lon -10gd-4 F-nw7000lc
```

Using Notepad++ in the above phrase I wanted to start a new line with the dates `Jan17` and `Feb2` but when I try `Jan\d+` to `\r\nJan` I get `Jan 11 Lon -2 ft-1 Janet Hall` without the 17 part of the date.

I can split the line again with `Feb\d+` to `\r\nFeb` but again the 2 part of the date is missing in the newly created line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a replacement group.

Try Find what: `Jan(\d+)`
 Replace: `\r\nJan\1`

Using `(\d+)` will capture the number into a replacement group.  Using `\1` will insert the captured characters in the first replacement group.

Comment: Or `\r\nJan\1` to put the newline at the beginning.